# How can I compare a column in a data frame by a value in a column with the same name/place in a second dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is organised in category by column and timestamp by row and a second dataframe with just one value per column as a threshold for the category.

I want to filter all values that are bigger than the threshold per column into a new dataframe. all values that are lower should just be set to 0.

```
input:
df1: 
time, category A, category B, category C, [...]
0, 1, 0, 2, […]
1, 4, 0, 5, […]
2, 6, 4, 3, […]
3, 8, 2, 2, […]
4, 3, 1, 4, […]

df2:
category A, category B, category C, [...]
2,3,3

output:
df3:
time, category A, category B, category C, [...]
0, 0, 0, 0, […]
1, 4, 0, 5, […]
2, 6, 4, 0, […]
3, 8, 0, 0, […]
4, 3, 0, 4, […]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way working with the underlying `NmmPy` arrays. I'm using up to `category C` from the provided sample:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('time')
pd.DataFrame((df1.values > df2.values)*df1.values, 
              columns = df1.columns, 
              index=df1.index)
             .reset_index()

    time  categoryA  categoryB  categoryC
0     0          0          0          0
1     1          4          0          5
2     2          6          4          0
3     3          8          0          0
4     4          3          0          4
```